# Import/append cell from one column (newrawdata) to another column (centrallibrary) if not preexisting - date error with Match Function

Tags: vba, excel, append, match

The code below uses the **match** function to check if a new set of values stored in the cells of Column C exists within a pre-existing range stored in Column A.

If so, then within the msgbox prompt, the row corresponding to that value is displayed.  Otherwise, error n/a is handled with an "if iserror" statement, which will append the value in question to the next empty row within Column A

Problem:

This works for Text and Numbers, but the match function doesn't seem to correctly return Dates.  A date value gets appended to the bottom of column A, regardless if pre-existing.

Likely error:

Formatting or value of date within the match function

To note:

Below is a line that is set as a comment, but creates an error for dates when uncommented - used to display which row the data is found within Column A

'MsgBox ("Data pre-exists in row " & MatchAns)

Happy to provide examples.

```
Option Explicit

Sub AppendNewRecords()


'example used - Column A, listed with a number of values including numbers, dates and text,
'Column C contains new raw data some matching Column A and some not,
'append new raw data not matching Column A to the end of Column A


'Declarations

    Dim NeAvRow As Integer
    Dim NeAvRecAdr As String


'Declarations

    Dim ImportRange As Long
    Dim MatchLookup As Variant
    Dim MatchArray As Variant
    Dim MatchAns As Variant



'Use the match function to see if record exists within the range

    For ImportRange = 1 To Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    MatchLookup = Cells(ImportRange, 3)
    MatchArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")

    MsgBox ("LookupValue " & MatchLookup)

    MatchAns = Application.Match(MatchLookup, MatchArray, 0)

'MsgBox ("Data pre-exists in row " & MatchAns)

'Find the address of the last empty row in a column

    NeAvRow = Worksheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NeAvRecAdr = "A" & NeAvRow + 1 'Next Available row for appending

If IsError(MatchAns) Then
    Range(NeAvRecAdr) = MatchLookup

End If

    Next ImportRange

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `Set` a range and date lookups perform better with raw values using the worksheet's [MATCH function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/match-function-0600e189-9f3c-4e4f-98c1-943a0eb427ca).

```
MatchLookup = Cells(ImportRange, 3).VALUE2   '<~~ use the raw date value for the lookup
SET MatchArray = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")   '<~~ SET the range

MsgBox ("LookupValue " & MatchLookup)

MatchAns = Application.Match(MatchLookup, MatchArray, 0)
```